# Wireless in HP Pavilion G4 2210la does not start with ubuntu 21.10

Tags: wireless, networking

Brand new notebook which came with Windows 8. I switched to ubuntu 12.10 and
Key on/off wireless does not turn on and wireless stays disable

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows, turn on Wireless, and come back to Ubuntu.

Now you should be able to work with wireless.

But I don't think you can control wireless with the wireless key in Ubuntu.

Atleast it doesn't work for me.

Comment: tHERE IS NO WINDOWS ANY MORE!!!

Comment: I switched to 12.04, and the Wireless key seems to be working for me. May be you can switch to 12.04 and try it out. But before that open `Network settings` and see if you have an entry for wireless.